# We say Siya Ram and Radheshyam why we say Shiv Parvati why don't we say Parvati Shiv?

Tags: shiva, name, parvati

There is always name of female before male like Siya Ram, Radheshyam then 
we say Shiv Parvati not Parvati Shiv.

Comment: We do say **Parvati Parameswara**, **Gauri Shankara** and for temples we say "Durga Malleswara", "Bramaramba Mallikarjuna" "Visalakshi Visveswara" and so on..

Comment: Than why we say shiv parvati

Comment: We do say "Uma MaheshwaraBhyo Namah"

Comment: This os not my question i want ans of that why the name of female come before male but it is not applicabe in shiv-parvati

Comment: This applies to all. See we say Siya-Ram ,Radhe-Krishna etc.during devotional singing , Bhajan etc. Or in Bhakti. But whenever we are talking in general about them or in discussion ,we say Krishna-Rukhmini ,Vishnu-Laxami , Krishna Radha etc.So we find calling as such mainly in songs. So we say Uma-Maheshwara in mantras etc.but when we are talking in general we say Shiva-Parvati.

Comment: Flow of the line goes well when we say Shiv Parvati, Sita Rama, Radhe Sham. But that flow won't be good in hearing of we say Parvati Shiva, Rama Sita, Krishna Radha. Speak by urself and see which suits better in pronunciation. There is no need to find logic in everything because some things are so simple to have any logic. Besides in case of Radhe Krishna, Lord Krishna grant boon to Radha that always her name comes before my name. Thats why we say Radhe Krishna. And also there is no rule that your have to say Shiva Parvati only. You can say Parvati Shiva also if you want. It's personal choice.

Comment: This is nothing except for ease of speaking. Just speak- "Parvati-Shiva", it is little less fluid than "Shiva-Parvati". So ease of flow is being taken into account, and not sone religious reason.

Comment: @Rishabh O my goodness, Your and my points just match. ;) I did not read your comment before posting my comment.

Comment: You don't know anything

Comment: There is a reason behind it

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that there are any such strict rules. As a proof, see the verse given below.

> LakshminArAyanau vAnidhAtArau **girijAshivau** |
>  Srigurum
>   gurupatnincha pitarAviti chintayet ||
>
> ..............
>
> Guru and Guru's consort (Gurupatni) should be thought of as one's own
>   parents. They are to be thought of as Lakshmi-NArAyana, VAni-BrahmA,
>   **GirijA-Shiva.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 12.35.**

Note that here GirijA is a name of Goddess PArvati. So, seemingly there is no such rule like we should only say Shiva-PArvati and not PArvati-Shiva.

Answer (score 1):

Shiva parvati are most beautiful eternal couples in all decades with complete family force
Shivena parvati
Shiva also parvati without parvati there is no shiva
If u say only shiva, goddess parvati present in his body entire half or may full body
If u say goddess parvati lord shiva present in her complete form
Shiva parvati are not different they are one their couple bonding such a way that they cant leave without each other
Without parvati their is no shiva nothing [image]

Answer (score 1):

The following scriptural excerpt answers this question .

**~ ब्रह्मवैवर्तपुराणम्/खण्डः ४ (श्रीकृष्णजन्मखण्डः)/अध्यायः ०५२
(Brahma vaivarta purana , Krishna janma khanda , Chapter 52).:**

> **जगन्माता च प्रकृतिः पुरुषश्च जगत्पिता ।। ३४ ।।
> गरीयसी त्रिजगतां माता शतगुणैः पितुः ।।
> राधाकृष्णेति गौरीशेत्येवं शब्दः श्रुतौ श्रुतः ।। ३५ ।।
> कृष्णराधेशगौरीति लोके न च कदा श्रुतः ।।**
>
> *Prakriti happens to be the mother of the universe and Purusha the father. In all the worlds, the glory of the mother is hundred times more than that of the father that's why the terms 'Radha-Krishna' and 'GaurIsha' is used in the vedas. Even in the universe, 'Krishna-Radha' or 'Isha-Gauri' is never heard.*
>
> **आदौ पुरुषमुच्चार्य पश्चात्प्रकृतिमुच्चरेत् ।। ३९ ।।
> स भवेन्मातृघाती च वेदातिक्रमणे मुने ।।**
>
> *The one who recites the name of Purusha first and Prakriti later on, he desecrates the Vedas and is considered to be a killer of the mother.*