# Why do Hindus say "Radhe Krishna"?

Tags: krishna, radha

Why do Hindus say "Radhe Krishna"? Why "Radhe" is pronounced before Krishna? Is there any story? Please tell me the story.

Comment: We say Sita Ram, Laxmi Narayan, Uma Mahesh too.. your Q is only specific to Radhe Shyam/Krishna or it's a general Q where you want to ask why we put female name before male name most of the time...

Comment: Generally we don't say "Parvati Shiva". You made my question wider than initial. Thanks for that. I want to know the answer in either way. @ YDS

Comment: But we say Uma Mahesh or Gauri Shankara too...

Comment: It seems sometimes rythm of words also matters for example...Luv Kush...but Kush is elder and it should be Kush Luv... similarly Arjun Bhim... Krishna Balram...and so on..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We say Siya Ram and Radheshyam why we say Shiv Parvati why don't we say Parvati Shiv?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21044/we-say-siya-ram-and-radheshyam-why-we-say-shiv-parvati-why-dont-we-say-parvati) and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13808

Comment: Answered here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57852/32510